# How can I use 'tensorboard' with tflite_model_maker? Is it possible to use custom_callbacks with tflite_model_maker?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, tensorboard

I have used "**tf.keras.callbacks.tensorboard**" with my custom keras-models. But I couldn't use it with tflite_model_maker for object detection. If it is possible please let me know... Thanks!

I could not find any information on the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/python/tflite_model_maker/object_detector/create)...

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Having the same question currently...

Comment: No. I haven't found it yet...

Answer (score 0):

Tensorboard dir is configured from class **EfficientDetModelSpec**.
you need parameter **model_dir**, there will be saved tensorboard logs along with model checkpoints

```
spec = model_spec.get('efficientdet_lite0', model_dir='mytbdir')
model = object_detector.create(train_data, model_spec=spec,...)

!ls mytbdir
checkpoint ckpt-1.data-00000-of-00001 ckpt-1.index
config.yaml train train_images

// usage from colab:
%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir tbdir
```